# Mac Command Line : how to rename all pictures with their actual content creation date

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

When showing info (cmd+I) on a picture file, we se a "Content created" date.
How can I use this date to batch rename pictures ?

Answer (score 8):

The `mdls` commands shows a bunch of useful info on picture files, including `kMDItemContentCreationDate`. Note this is is note the creation date, so if the picture was taken on a phone and then copied a bunch of times, you still get the actual date the picture was taken (pretty useful for renaming pictures.)

Here is a script that, for each file in the current folder, renames the file with the date given by `kMDItemContentCreationDate, in format YYYY-MM-DD_HH-mm-ss.previousFileExtension :

```
for f in *.*; do 
   mv "$f" "$(mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate "$f" | sed s/kMDItemContentCreationDate...// | sed s/.+0000// | sed s/:/-/g | sed s/\ /_/g).${f##*.}"; 
done
```

Comment: Nice, though there's something wrong with it, as I get less pictures after running the command than I had before. (I suspect an issue with duplicate datetimes and/or files that do not have kMDItemContentCreationDate set.)

Comment: This worked perfectly on macOS Big Sur! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@alexsedlex
Thanks for the script

I faced the same problem like @FabienSnauwaert and had less files after running the script. I modified the script to add a random number to the file name like:

```
YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS.RRRRR.*
```

so that you shouldn't lose files:

```bash
for f in *.*; do
   mv "$f" "$(mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate "$f" | sed s/kMDItemContentCreationDate...// | sed s/.+0000// | sed s/:/-/g | sed s/\ /_/g).$RANDOM.${f##*.}";
done
```

Answer (score -1):

alexsedlex has a great answer but I added the `--raw` flag to the `mdls` command and then didn't need to use `sed` but could use `cut` instead.  So this is just a slightly simpler variation.

```bash
for f in *.* 
do 
  creation_date=$(mdls --raw -name kMDItemContentCreationDate "$f" | cut -c 1-10 )
  new_file_name="${creation_date}_$f"
  mv -v "$f" "$new_file_name"; 
done
```